# How to fill a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to fill this gridview :

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvReportingStockComp" runat="server">

<Columns>

<asp:BoundField DataField="cod_wo" HeaderText="N° OF" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="composant" HeaderText="Composant" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="besoin" HeaderText="Besoin/OF" />

</Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

with a code behind C#~, but I don't know what doesn't work with it :

```
OracleConnection oConnexion = new OracleConnection();
oConnexion.ConnectionString = "X";
oConnexion.Open();

string requete = SELECT cod_wo, composant, ROUND((wo_qty / (qty_revue * qte_besoin)) - qte_assignee,2) \"BESOIN\" FROM w";

OracleCommand cmdReqStockComp = new OracleCommand(requete);
cmdReqStockComp.Connection = oConnexion;
OracleDataReader readerReqStockComp = cmdReqStockComp.ExecuteReader();

gvReportingStockComp.DataSource = readerReqStockComp;
gvReportingStockComp.DataBind();

oConnexion.Close();
oConnexion.Dispose();
```

[image: Bizarre]

Comment: Where do you fill the grid?

Comment: Also close and dispose your reader after bind. That's a hit and not the answer

Comment: My gridview is "gvReportingStockComp". I fill it DataBind or Datasource but I don't understand, my data appears twice.

Comment: debug it and see if there are results in there. Does the DataFields match exactly the fields of the query?

Comment: _"but I don't know what doesn't work with it"_ How should we know what's not working if even you don't know?

Comment: And where are you doing that databind? Maybe you are not doing it in the proper place. Give more code and the function where that C# belongs to please

Comment: For example, normally I must have three columns which are named : N° OF, Composant and Besoin/OF.
But my result is these three columns and again this three columns but with different name...

Comment: Ok I copy it in few seconds :)

Comment: DataField has to be the same name EXACTLY as the column on your database, because the GV needs to know where each column is going. Try it.

Comment: Ok thanks. Alias is important ?

Comment: Because the real query is :
SELECT w.cod_wo,"
                                        + " w.composant,"
                                        + " ROUND((w.wo_qty / (w.qty_revue * w.qte_besoin)) - w.qte_assignee,2) \"BESOIN\","
                                        + " ROUND(s.besoin_total,2) \"BESOIN_T\","
                                        + " w.stock_dispo,"
                                        + " ROUND(w.stock_dispo - s.besoin_total,2) \"QTE_RESTANTE\""
                                        + " FROM w

Comment: can you run your query in sql server or whatever you are using? and post the result table in an image please?

Comment: Yes, I'm adding a link to my question with an image ;)

Comment: No idea ? It give me a headache ^^

Comment: The doubling of the columns is because you have not set AutoGenerateColumns to false.  Set that and you'll only get the columns you specify.

Answer (score 0):

requete needs to be in quotes.

```
string requete = "SELECT cod_wo, composant, ROUND((wo_qty / (qty_revue * qte_besoin)) - qte_assignee,2) \"BESOIN\" FROM w";
```